# Snap to angle freehand pen/pencil tool in Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, paperjs

#### What I'm currently doing

I'm trying to build a freehand pencil tool in HTML5 Canvas (using Paper.js as the Canvas wrapper).

#### What I want to do

I'd like to allow the user to draw *straight lines* (when Shift is pressed down for example) while drawing. This straight line should "snap", ideally, to an 8-directional snapping "radius".

#### What I tried (which is not exactly what I need).

I've tried a very simple solution where I snap the mouse point to a near rounded point. This works somehow fine but it's not exactly a snap-to-angle tool, it's more like a snap to an invisible grid kind-of-tool.

```
  mousedrag: function(event) {
    var snapped = {x: snap(event.point.x), y: snap(event.point.y)};

    // add "snapped" drag point
    path.add(snapped.x, snapped.y);
  }

  // convert a number to a rounded snap
  function snap(x, div) { 
    return Math.round(x/div)*div; 
  };
```

Here's an interactive [Sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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) of what I'm currently doing (holding Shift snaps to a grid, releasing resumes regular freehand drawing)

---

Can anyone give me an indication on how to proceed for snapping to an angle instead of a grid?

#### Notes:

- Although I'm using Canvas/Paper.js, I understand that the solution to the problem is independent of the rendering tech I'm using, so any JS-based solution (either SVG or Canvas, wrapper or without) should give me some good foundations on how to proceed.
- I'm having a feeling that the solution might involve `Math.atan()` or something along those lines, instead of my solution where I snap to a rounded `Math.round` point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you juste change one or two lines in your code, you [get something](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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) which might be close to what you want:

```
// ...

function onMouseDrag(event) {
    // if shift is down we transform the mousepoint
    // to a "snapped point", else add the mousepoint as it is.
    if(shiftDown)
    {
        var snapPoint = new Point(snap(event.point.x), snap(event.point.y));
        myPath.lastSegment.point = snapPoint;
    }
    else 
    {
        var snapPoint = event.point;
        myPath.add(snapPoint);
    }
}

// ...
```

You can easily [modify this to snap the angle](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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) instead of the position.

```
function onMouseDrag(event) {
    // if shift is down we transform the mousepoint
    // to a "snapped point", else add the mousepoint as it is.
    if(shiftDown)
    {
        var vector = event.point - myPath.lastSegment.previous.point;
        vector.angle = Math.round(vector.angle/angleSnap)*angleSnap;
        myPath.lastSegment.point = myPath.lastSegment.previous.point + vector;
    }
    else 
    {
        var snapPoint = event.point;
        myPath.add(snapPoint);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks neat - Adding a `myPath.add(event.point)` in the `mouseDown` handler will also allow to *start* drawing straight-lines. Mind if I edit your answer to add this as well?

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides go ahead!

Answer (score 3):

The basis of limiting drawing to straight lines is fairly straightforward -- pun intended :-)

**When the user drags the mouse, calculate the nearest point on an imaginary line running at your desired angle.**

Here is how to calculate the point on a line that is closest  to the mouse:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
  var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  offsetX=BB.left;
  offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }
window.onresize=function(e){ reOffset(); }

var lineStart={x:50,y:50};
var lineEnd={x:250,y:250};
var cr=15;

draw({x:-20,y:-20},'green');

$("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});

//////////////////////////////////

function draw(pt,fill){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(lineStart.x,lineStart.y);
  ctx.lineTo(lineEnd.x,lineEnd.y);
  ctx.strokeStyle='black';
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(pt.x,pt.y,5,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle=fill;
  ctx.fill();
}

// Find line segment point closest to source point
// [x0,y0] to [x1,y1] define a line segment
// [cx,cy] is source point 
function calcClosestPtOnSegment(x0,y0,x1,y1,cx,cy,cr){

  // calc delta distance: source point to line start
  var dx=cx-x0;
  var dy=cy-y0;

  // calc delta distance: line start to end
  var dxx=x1-x0;
  var dyy=y1-y0;

  // Calc position on line normalized between 0.00 & 1.00
  // == dot product divided by delta line distances squared
  var t=(dx*dxx+dy*dyy)/(dxx*dxx+dyy*dyy);

  // calc nearest pt on line
  var x=x0+dxx*t;
  var y=y0+dyy*t;

  // clamp results to being on the segment
  if(t<0){x=x0;y=y0;}
  if(t>1){x=x1;y=y1;}

  return({ 
    x:x, y:y, 
    isColliding:((cx-x)*(cx-x)+(cy-y)*(cy-y)) < cr*cr,
    isOnSegment:(t>=0 && t<=1),
  });
}

function handleMouseMove(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  var p=calcClosestPtOnSegment(
    lineStart.x,lineStart.y,lineEnd.x,lineEnd.y,
    mouseX,mouseY,cr);
  var fill=(p.isOnSegment)?'green':'red';

  draw(p,fill);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(mouseX,mouseY,cr,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.strokeStyle=p.isColliding?'green':'blue';
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Move mouse to see closest point on angled line segment.<br>Closest point is green (or red if beyond segment) </h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```